# Write to a variable in another scope?

Tags: go

I am newbie in Golang, and I get stuck with setting value of variable from anonymous function (another scope). Now I am using goquery.

For example I've following:

```
models := []model.User{}

doc.Find(".ff").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
     //...

    models := append(models, model.User{})
})
```

And this does not work. How can I append new model to models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:=` declares and initializes a new variable, while `=` assigns to an existing variable.

So change your code to

```
models = append(models, model.User{})
```

Comment: Lol, after using PHP I was confused. I thought this is a problem with scopes. Thanks.